# Changing C stack pointer address (pointed to)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I think I maybe finally have a little pointer-understanding-breakthrough, but I am struggling with a seemingly simple problem, I would like to make a pointer point to the same memory address as another pointer, example:

```
char* foo = "foo"; // memory address: 0x7ffdabc4dbf8
char* bar = "bar"; // memory address: 0x7ffdabc4dbf0
```

How do I point foo to the same address as bar? I know how to change the value, example:

```
foo = bar; // foo is now "bar" but the memory address is the same as before
```

I have experimented a little:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>

void print_info(char* string1, char* string2) {
    printf("Memory address of string1: %p\n", &string1);
    printf("Memory address of string2: %p\n", &string2);
    printf("Value of string1: %s\n", string1);
    printf("Value of string2: %s\n", string2);
    printf("\n");
}

void change(char** ptr1, char** ptr2) {
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
}

int main() {

    printf("Initial values: string1 = \"foo\" string2 = \"bar\"\n\n");

    char* string1 = "foo"; // Pointer to a string literal?
    char* string2 = "bar"; // Pointer to a string literal?

    print_info(string1, string2);

    // Modifying value, the pointer have the same memory address as before
    string1 = string2;
    printf("string1 = string2\n\n");

    print_info(string1, string2);

    string2 = "bas";
    printf("string2 = \"bas\"\n\n");

    print_info(string1, string2);

    change(&string1, &string2);
    printf("change(&string1, &string2)\n\n");

    print_info(string1, string2);

    char *ptr = string1;
    printf("char *ptr = string1\n\n");

    printf("Memory address of ptr: %p\n", &ptr);
    printf("Value of ptr: %s\n\n", ptr);

    printf("Trying to change pointers directly:\n\n");

    printf("&string1 = &string2\n");
    printf("GCC: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment\n\n");
    //&string1 = &string2;

    printf("string1 = &string2\n");
    printf("GCC: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char **’\n\n");
    string1 = &string2;
    print_info(string1, string2);

    printf("&string1 = *string2\n");
    printf("GCC: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment\n\n");
    //&string1 = *string2;
    //print_info(string1, string2);

    printf("string1 = *string2\n");
    printf("GCC: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘char’ makes pointer from integer without a cast\n\n");
    //string1 = *string2;
    //print_info(string1, string2);
    printf("Segmentation fault (core dumped)\n\n");

    printf("*string1 = &string2\n");
    printf("GCC: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char **’ makes integer from pointer without a cast\n\n");
    *string1 = &string2;
    print_info(string1, string2);
    printf("Corruption?\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Initial values: string1 = "foo" string2 = "bar"

Memory address of string1: 0x7fffc52760b8
Memory address of string2: 0x7fffc52760b0
Value of string1: foo
Value of string2: bar

string1 = string2

Memory address of string1: 0x7fffc52760b8
Memory address of string2: 0x7fffc52760b0
Value of string1: bar
Value of string2: bar

string2 = "bas"

Memory address of string1: 0x7fffc52760b8
Memory address of string2: 0x7fffc52760b0
Value of string1: bar
Value of string2: bas

change(&string1, &string2)

Memory address of string1: 0x7fffc52760b8
Memory address of string2: 0x7fffc52760b0
Value of string1: bas
Value of string2: bas

char *ptr = string1

Memory address of ptr: 0x7fffc52760d8
Value of ptr: bas

Trying to change pointers directly:

&string1 = &string2
GCC: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

string1 = &string2
GCC: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char **’

Memory address of string1: 0x7fffc52760b8
Memory address of string2: 0x7fffc52760b0
Value of string1: � @
Value of string2: bas

&string1 = *string2
GCC: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

string1 = *string2
GCC: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘char’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

*string1 = &string2
GCC: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char **’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Memory address of string1: 0x7fffc52760b8
Memory address of string2: 0x7fffc52760b0
Value of string1: � @
Value of string2: 

Corruption?
```

Is it possible to chang the address pointed to by a stack pointer? or is it only possible with heap pointers? (malloc?)

Comment: After `string1 = string2`, the two pointers point to the same memory, "bar". The two addresses that you print are of the `string1` and `string2` variables themselves, which are of course still different.

Comment: You have *two* addresses - the address of the pointer itself, and the address of what it point to. You can only change the second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of your problem seems to be right at the start:

```
void print_info(char* string1, char* string2) {
    printf("Memory address of string1: %p\n", &string1);
    printf("Memory address of string2: %p\n", &string2);
```

This prints the location where `print_info` stores its arguments.

You probably wanted

```
void print_info(char* string1, char* string2) {
    printf("Memory address where string1 points to: %p\n", string1);
    printf("Memory address where string2 points to: %p\n", string2);
```

Answer (score 5):

After the definitions

```
char* foo = "foo";
char* bar = "bar";
```

your memory looks something like

```
+-----+       +-------+
| foo | ----> | "foo" |
+-----+       +-------+

+-----+       +-------+
| bar | ----> | "bar" |
+-----+       +-------+
```

Then you do the assignment:

```
foo = bar;
```

Which leads to the memory looking something like this instead:

```
+-----+       +-------+
| foo | -\    | "foo" |
+-----+  |    +-------+
         |
+-----+  |    +-------+
| bar | ->--> | "bar" |
+-----+       +-------+
```

Now both the variables `foo` and `bar` are pointing to the same thing, but the variables themselves are still separate and distinct entities with their own memory allocated for them.

---

On a different note, in C all literal strings (like for example `"foo"`) are not supposed to be modified. They are in essence *read-only*. That's why it's recommended to use `const char *` variables to point to them. That will allow the compiler to catch attempts to modify the literal strings through the pointer variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a;
int *ptr1 = &a;  // address of a is asigned to ptr1
int *ptr2 = ptr1;   // address of ptr1 is asigned to ptr2

printf("Address of a: %d",&a);
printf("\nAddress of ptr1: %d",ptr1);
printf("\nAddress of ptr2: %d",ptr2);

int b;
ptr1 = &b;
ptr2 = ptr1;

printf("\n\n");
printf("Address of a: %d",&b);
printf("\nAddress of ptr1: %d",ptr1);
printf("\nAddress of ptr2: %d",ptr2);

return 0;
}
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4B8r.png)

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Don' post code only answers withput any explanation.

Comment: I am new stackoverflow user, I didnt knew that

Comment: You can [edit] your answer in order to improve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).